# NSInternalInconsistencyException being returned from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: when using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am fairly new to Objective C and to iOS development in general, and I'm still trying to get a feel for it.  But I am trying to make a simple iOS app with (as of right now) a UITableViewController as the main page using Storyboards.  I am just trying to get the cells to appear. My code is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // Return the number of sections.
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // Return the number of rows in the section.
   return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cervical_patterns = @"cervical_patterns";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cervical_patterns"];

   return cell;
}
```

I have closely followed the second iOS Birdwatching tutorial app [(link)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318) and have previously gotten a UITableViewController to be viewable in the simulator.  But I can't figure out why this is not working like the birdwatching app.

The error I am getting is :

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say you are using a UITabViewController and trying to get the tabs to appear BUT your code is for a UITableView with cells.  So which is it? A Tab View or a Table View?  Also, your question makes no sense: 1) It refers to a birdwatching app with no links (and I'm not searching for some random app) and 2)You are getting an error and not telling us what error you have.  ADD the error to your question and we may be able to help.

Comment: Appologies I was doing some extjs programming before hand mixed up tab and table whoopsie.  [BirdWatching APP](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318). My error was added below but here it is again: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0):

So you are using a Storyboards and a UITableViewController.  This means you need to:

1. Go to your Storyboard
2. Click on the first cell in your Table View
3. Make sure the Utilities (window on the right) is showing
4. Click on the Attribute Inspector
5. Change "Style" from "Custom" to "Basic" (use Custom if you have customized the cell)
6. Click on Identifier and make sure it is the same as in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method (cervical_patterns)

Also check that you have set the class correctly:

1. Go to your Storyboard
2. Click on the black bar under your Table View
3. Make sure the Utilities (window on the right) is showing
4. Click on the Identity Inspector
5. Make sure your custom class is selected in the drop down

I have just done this in XCode and it works perfectly (note that **no** `(cell == nil)` code is required).  Exact code below:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cervical_patterns";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the text and graphics of the cell

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to actually create the cell, like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cervical_patterns = @"cervical_patterns";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cervical_patterns"];

    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
               initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:cervical_patterns ] autorelease];

    }

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: Note, I'm assuming you aren't using ARC

Comment: No I am not.  How do I know I'm using it?

Comment: It would have been when you first created the project under iOS 5

Comment: Your code only applies if both Storyboards, the TableViewController and iOS5+ are NOT being used.  Otherwise `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is guaranteed to return a cell (See the iOS 5 Release Notes section Configuring Table Views: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/_index.html).

Comment: Dont knock my answer, the only thing I added to the original code is the actual creation of the cell, which you do have to do.

Comment: @firestream: Calm down - no one is "knocking" your answer (although it contains redundant code under iOS 5 and Storyboards as indicated in the question).  Please follow the link above and read the iOS 5 release notes. I would note, however, that you haven't actually addressed the question (yet) as the question does not currently contain enough info to solve the (unidentified) error.

Comment: Sorry I did forget to put the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

The problem is I'm using iOS 5.1 and storyboard.

Comment: my answer creates the cell you need

Comment: With the code above in place (redundant or not) takes care of the error as expected.  But, now none of my cells are showing up. It's like they were never created.